# Using d3 4.0 with TypeScript throws "Cannot read property 'format' of undefined"

Tags: d3.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have the following code on a 'Counter.ts' (TypeScript) file:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<CounterState> = (state, action) => {
    console.log(someD3Name.ascending);   // command 1
    console.log(someD3Name.time.format); // command 2
    return state || { count: 0 };
};
```

At run time, only "command 1" will succeed. "command 2" will fail with the following message:

```
Cannot read property 'format' of undefined
```

I understand that now d3 4.0 has a flat namespace (from https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

```
every symbol in D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x. For example, d3.scale.linear is now d3.scaleLinear
```

At run time, indeed 'timeFormat' exists, but if I use that on the TypeScript file, then the Typescript compiler (transpiler?) will throw the following error

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/store/Counter.ts
(37,27): error TS2339: Property 'timeFormat' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.
```

What am I missing? If the problem is the Typescript definition file is out-of-date, as d3 4.0 was just released, is there another way of using d3 4.0 with TypeScript?

### My environment

I'm trying to add d3 to the website generated with this command

```
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

This command generates a ASP.NET Core with React+Redux SPA with default Webpack+Babel. I am adding d3 like this

```
npm install d3 --save
tsd install d3 --save
```

Then, on any page (in my case Counter.ts):

```
import * as someD3Name from 'd3';
```